# How can i make a hidden window with bat files ?

Tags: batch-file, hidden

i need to make a batch file that have a hidden process and window for the users
i have already my batches file and want to make one of them hidden 
vbs can't make that or any programming language ?

Comment: could you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

here you can find multiple ways to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284876/what-are-the-different-ways-to-start-a-hidden-process-with-batch-file-and-what-a

Probably the best is with **Win32_ProcessStartup** as it returns also the pid of the started process.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\file.bat" & Chr(34), 0    
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

with Vbs and call the bat file this is the way

Answer (score 0):

Use the start command:

```
start /b my.bat
```

Refer to: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx